# Angularjs using function direct in ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to use a `function` direct in `ng-click`? 
I have tried to do this step, but not work `console: Error: [$parse:syntax]`

My code with I have tried:

```
<button ng-click="function(){test='NewTest';}"></button>
<h1>{{test}}</h1>
```

and the test must be a `scope` it must return `$scope.test='NewTest';`

> **Note**: Don't use `controller` or direct scope like `ng-click="test='NewTest'"` or any other services, please use only direct function.

Answer (score -1):

NO You cannot do that. Without using a function, you can directly change the $scope variable as follows,

```
button ng-click="test='NewTest'"></button>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var angularApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
angularApp.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.test ='something;'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
{{test}}
<button ng-click="test='NewTest'">change me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: No you cannot use function, so.i have provided alternative way

Answer (score -1):

To call a function in ng-click you must put it in your controller and attach it to the scope.

```
<button ng-click="setTest()">Click</button>
<h1>{{test}}</h1>
```

The following is a simple controller to do this:

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', function ( $scope ) {

    $scope.setTest = function setTest(){
        return $scope.test='NewTest';
    }

});
```